# Jetty config without resourceBase

Tags: scala, jetty, scalatra

I have a Scalatra with Jetty and it is serving REST API at the moment. No static context served at all. However, it seems I cannot skip setting resourceBase without getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No resourceBase or war set for context
```

Do I have to point it to some empty directory or is there some other option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `resourceBase` is required, and it is used for more than just static content.

It's also the location for configuration that the `ServletContext` needs.

Point it at an empty directory in your jar file if you don't even have that.